# Back to line in API calls with fetch for Telegram bot

Tags: javascript, telegram, fetch-api, telegram-bot

I am new to APIs and I want to create a Telegram-Bot with JavaScript that sends notifications from an HTML form.

I am using the fetch command with the API this way:

```
    var TOKEN = "";
    var chatID = "";
    var api = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendMessage?chat_id="+chatID+"&text=";
    // getting the message from the form
    var message = document.getElementById('message').replace(/ /g,"%20");
    // call fetch
    fetch(api + "New%20Message:%20" + message);
```

The thing is that this only works on a message that is on one line. In case the message returns to the line, it creates weird text:

> "Hello
>
> World!"

becomes "HelloWorld!". Is there any way to make the API call with a message that goes back to lines within one Fetch call?

I want to get this output:

> "New Message: Hello
>
> World!"

without breaking the fetch method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I was able to fix this.

It just has to do with the ASCII coding. "%20" is a space, for a carriage return, which is the return to line is "%0D". This works just fine for the API.

```
message = (string Message).replace(/ /g, '%20').split('\n').join('%0A');
fetch(api + "New%20Message:%20" + message);
```

That way You can get both the spaces and the return to lines from the call.